# Sending an API call from webapp via local machin

Tags: postman, vpn, postman-native-app

I am wondering if there is a way I can send an API request from an app I am building through the local machine.

I have to make a call on the VPN, and when I make it from my browser, the call gets blocked. However, when I make the call from postman desktop app, the call works.

I have also tried this via Postman agent. If I make the call on Postman web, without the agent, the call does not work. However, if I make the call with Postman agent and its connected to Postman desktop, the call will work.

Is there a way I can mimic the Postman web + Postman agent process for my own web app?

I want to send an API call from my web browser to through my machines internet.

Comment: In what way does it get blocked? I strongly suspect you're hitting CORS issues.

Comment: Ive successfully been able to run the call and get a 200 repsonse

In the postman desktop app
Entering the url in the browser
In postman web with postman desktop agent

Ive not been able to run the call (i dont get a response, its provides me with this error → The host ------ . com is not valid)

All 5 of these scenarios is when the companies AWS VPN is turned on. If the VPN is off, the request will not work regardless.

Comment: What browser? Perhaps it's using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_over_HTTPS and thus bypassing the VPN's DNS servers?